# JDBC Invalid column index exception

Tags: jdbc, sqlexception

for SQL Query

```sql
SELECT M.TXREFNO,M.PROCESSDATE 
WHERE F.PROCESSID=? AND (M.COUNTRYCODE IN (?) OR M.COUNTRYCODE IS NULL)
AND (M.TXREFNO=?)
```

I have passed the string as

```java
stmt.setString(3, entry.getValue().toString());
stmt.setString(2, entry.getValue().toString());
stmt.setString(1, entry.getValue().toString());
```

but its showing `Invalid column index Exception`.

Comment: and what is the value in entry

Comment: Post the relevant code and the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Thats contains some value as String

Comment: Have you tried setting the strings in ascending order? Also: include the full exception stactrace, and specify your database + version and driver + version as it might be relevant.